# How to define a route that only accepts a slug and id?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications

What kind of a route do I need in order to catch urls like `mydowmain.com/slug/id` like:

```
http://mydomain.com/dont-ask-what-you-can-do-for-stackoverflow/12
```

How can I do this in asp.net mvc3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it worked for me

```
Routes.MapRoute("ViewArticle", "{slug}/{id}",
                new { controller = "articles", action = "view", id = "", slug = "" },
                new { id = @"\d+" });

Routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = "" });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `RouteCollection.MapRoute()` method in your `Application_Start()` method in your `global.asax.cs` file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Slug", // Route name
                "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "YourControllerToCall", action = "YourAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

This code will register your desired route, and will map this to the `YourControllerToCall` controller (obviously put there what controller you want mapped to this route), and the action you need, as well as an optional `id` (if you want it optional, of course).

Comment: @am  what happened, sharks route looks fine - he just left out the route constraint which you didnt mention was necessary

Comment: @Adam Tuliper, I put his route in and tested the url but it didn't get picked up. I also suspect his route wasn't going to work because it requires the url to include an action. In my answer however the url doesn't need to include an action. Only a string (the slug) and the id for the article